# Can I use any digital component to avoid 7805 killing my microcontroller directly when its ground is disconnected (hence 12v goes to uC directly)?

Tags: zener, atmega328p, scr, 7805

My idea is to have an intermediate cheap component that will blow-up before my uC if the voltage goes above 5v from 7805 (or even some fuse, but I am not sure if a fuse will blow-up with over-voltage like it blows-up with over-current). I have lost many Atmega328P chips because of 7805 accidentally supplying 12v to them. I have heard of SCR - is it the component I am looking for which blows-up with voltage?

Also, please tell me how to use a zener with 7805.

Comment: There are no such things as voltage fuses that blow when the voltage is too high. But there are components that will try their best to clamp the voltage below a certain level before too overheat and fry. You connect them between the line being clamped and GND. Zeners and TVS diodes. But I think you ought to just fix the origin of the problem: the reason why your ground keeps getting disconnected so easily. That's indicative of your construction methods being faulty and trying to fix it with a protective device is like making sure everyone wears hard hats indoors instead of fixing the ceiling.

Comment: Any component except an insulator will go to 12v when you disconnect it from ground. Including the zener. Though you would have to disconnect both the zener and the 7805 for that to become a problem.

Comment: DKNguyen - thanks. I was wondering how to place my 5.1v Zener diode, so now I know that I need to connect it between 5v output of 7805 and GND. But I am still not sure about polarity. Where should I connect cathode of Zener?

Comment: Piojo - that is a wonderful info about how components will pass 12v to my ICs. The reason they keep doing it is because I was testing it on breadboard and they werent soldered-in. Do you mean that both zener and 7805 will have to be disconnected form ground to pass 12v to my uC? If so, that sounds like placing a zener to 7805 having grounds connected separately is beneficial then

Comment: I second DKNguyen feedback, **fix the cause, not the symptom.** Consider soldering the regulator to a adapter board and stick that into your bread board. A pin header will make more reliable contact than the leads of the component. You might even solder the caps to the adapter board also. A cut prototyping board may suffice. There are probably even proper TO92 adapter commercially available.

Comment: Awesome. I didnt think of this to solder 7805 and then pass the wire or adapter contacts to breadboard, so even if breadboard contacts are loose, at least 7805 is fixed by soldering and wont cause chaos. Again, thank you all

Comment: I think my earlier comment is not so relevant to the situation, now that I understand it better. What I meant to say is that all normal components: diodes, reverse biased diodes, resistors--all will have zero voltage drop when they have no current flow.

Comment: Well, actually, not really. In your case, you can assume so, but on physics, you always have static charges, bimetal effects, and piezo effects which all induce voltages so actually it is never really zero voltage drop and it is good to know if you start to do precise analog.

Comment: A component that "blows up" will fail open-circuit allowing the high voltage through to your circuit. You want a solution that doesn't blow up but either "clamps" or "crowbars" the circuit. Solve the problem by using a 5 V USB PSU instead.

Comment: Hi transistor. I need 12v input to run 12v fans. Can I still use 5v usb psu while getting 12v for my fans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use a fuse in conjunction with a relatively big Zener diode.

This is not perfect but cheap and simple and will work in most cases.

If the input voltage goes above the Zener voltage (in this case 5.4V) the Zener will short and the fuse will blow.

For the fuse, you can use a PTC resettable fuse

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJLbKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A better way is to use a voltage clamp circuit instead of a zener.

Another solution is to use an LDO (or other types of regulator) for the input but you need to consider the voltage drop caused.

Overvoltage protection circuit (note this circuit will cause a voltage drop, LDO IMO is simpler):
[image]
https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/overvoltage-protection-circuit

Comment: Thanks for answer, Damien. I am interested to know about how to use a voltage clamp? I already use an LDO 7805, but since it was on breadboard, it kept disconnecting from ground and frying my uC. People assured me it wont happen on my commercial pcb product, btu now I am paranoid. I do have 500mA fuses. Are they fine?

Comment: Also, am I right that zener is placed in reverse-biased setting in your above diagram which will start conducting only when the breakdown voltage occurs and draw much current to blow the fuse?

Comment: It is correct. The fuse has to be designed so that it will hold at the nominal current use of your circuit. On a PCB it is unlikely a component would get unsoldered, if it does, then there is a manufacturing issue and anyway the rest your board probably won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Damien. I do have a zener of 5.1 rating and a fuse of 500mA. Do I need a lesser value fuse? I think if zener will draw infinite curent then 500 mA should suffice because my other devices in circuit (an OLED display, an RGB led, a buzzer, two 0.2 A fans) can draw upto 500mA. But I still need an opinion on this

Comment: Just make sure the Zener can draw more current than the fuse can hold (for a short time). 500mA at 5V is 2.5W.

Comment: 1N5339BRLG would work

Comment: Sure. And I will also ask my supplier about wattage of my zener to make sure it doesnt burn

Comment: Thank you for part number Damien

Comment: Hi Damien. Thank you for updating your schematics. Just one question, what is Q1 tansistor here? My 7805 LDO? Also, I just tested the zener-fuse circuit and the fuse did blow-up, but I think i need better quality fuses which blow-up instantly as this one took enough time that the LED load melted.

Comment: Q1 will stop conducting if the load is above 5.1V - Vbe. Yes you have different types of fuse, Fast and Slow, make sure to use the fast ones. I suggest using PTC fuse

Comment: Yes, but I have a 12volt input and 7805. I am not sure where to put my 7805 in your circuit? Q1 is 7805 or some other transistor?

Comment: It would be at the input but as the comments said, if you already have an LDO in your circuit, you rather make sure that it is well connected.

Comment: I see. So, your schemtaic with zener and resistance is at output of 7805 which will protect the load if the output voltage is more than 5.1 volts, right?

Comment: I came across this too -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouPBj.png where zener is at input side of 7805, so I am confused

Comment: It's a different circuit, which is a voltage clamp. (works the same way as the Zener version but can handle higher current than a Zener alone). Overall there are many different solutions possible, all depends on the constraints and needs.

Comment: Ah ok. My only requirement is to get 4.6v to 5.1 at output voltage for my uC. And in case of any accidental fluctuations at input or 7805, my output circuitry is safe as it includes expensive components.

EDIT:Can you suggest which Q1 I can use for my circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to add another regulator, but it has to be an LDO regulator, not a 7805.

For example, the [AP2210N-5.0TRG1](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2210.pdf) has only a few hundred mV drop at 100-200mA and can handle up to +15V in. It's advertised as being able to withstand negative inputs as well, but I don't see a specifically stated voltage limit on that. Be sure to use the recommended input/output capacitors or it can go unstable.

If you do supply +12V the regulator will likely go into thermal limiting, which is not good for the part, but it will protect the chip it's connected to.

---

That's to answer your question, but really you need to fix the problem at the source as DKNguyen says, for example, by soldering the 7805 into a bit of perf board so the GND pin is solidly connected.